# How to clean the mess after items deletion using model()

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below creates a single QListView with model. Clicking its item deletes it from the model. But `QListView` still reports that the number of model's items remains unchanged (like there were no items deleted). Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

```
class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[] 
        self.modelDict={}       

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.modelDict)   

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        if not (0 <= index.row() < len(self.items)):
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole:
            key=str(index.data().toString())
            returnedValue=self.modelDict.get(key)
            return QtCore.QVariant(returnedValue) 

        elif role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row=index.row()
            itemTitle=self.items[row]
            return QtCore.QVariant(itemTitle) 

    def addItems(self):
        for key in self.modelDict:
            index=QtCore.QModelIndex()
            self.beginInsertRows(index, 0, 0)
            self.items.append(key)

            inst=self.modelDict.get(key)
            self.setData(index, QtCore.QVariant(inst), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)            

        self.endInsertRows()        

    def removeByIndex(self, index):
        if not index.isValid(): return
        row=index.row()
        self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, 0)
        self.items=self.items[:row]+self.items[row+1:]
        self.endRemoveRows()

class ListView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListView, self).__init__()
        self.model= Model()
        self.model.modelDict=elements
        self.model.addItems()
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.clicked.connect(self.itemClicked)
        self.show()

    def itemClicked(self, index):   
        print 'NUMBER OF ITEMS BEFORE DELETE: %s'%self.model.rowCount()   
        self.model.removeByIndex(index)
        print 'NUMBER OF ITEMS AFTER DELETE: %s'%self.model.rowCount()          

window=ListView()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully working example on how to delete items from model.

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[] 
        self.modelDict={}       

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)   

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        if not (0 <= index.row() < len(self.items)):
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole:
            key=str(index.data().toString())
            returnedValue=self.modelDict.get(key)
            return QtCore.QVariant(returnedValue) 

        elif role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row=index.row()
            itemTitle=self.items[row]
            return QtCore.QVariant(itemTitle) 

    def addItems(self):
        for key in self.modelDict:
            index=QtCore.QModelIndex()
            self.beginInsertRows(index, 0, 0)
            self.items.append(key)

            inst=self.modelDict.get(key)
            self.setData(index, QtCore.QVariant(inst), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)            

        self.endInsertRows()        

    def removeByIndex(self, index):
        if not index.isValid(): return
        row=index.row()
        self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, 0)
        self.items=self.items[:row]+self.items[row+1:]
        key=str(index.data().toString())
        if self.modelDict.get(key): self.modelDict.pop(key,None)
        self.endRemoveRows()

class ListView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListView, self).__init__()
        self.model= Model()
        self.model.modelDict=elements
        self.model.addItems()
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.clicked.connect(self.itemClicked)
        self.show()

    def itemClicked(self, index):   
        print 'NUMBER OF ITEMS BEFORE DELETE: %s'%self.model.rowCount()   
        self.model.removeByIndex(index)
        print 'NUMBER OF ITEMS AFTER DELETE: %s'%self.model.rowCount()          

window=ListView()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: can you highly the changes you made? because having to make a diff is regrettable.